# vue-router Route with name does not exist

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a `vue` component that contains a method, the method contains this router push that tries to push to another `vue` component:

**GetAnimal.vue**:

```js
...
this.$router.push({
    name: "/viewanimal",
});
...
```

I have this mappings for the router:

**router.js**:

```js
{
    path: "/viewanimal",
    component: () => import('./views/DisplayAnimal.vue')
},
{
    path: "/getanimal",
    component: () => import('./views/GetAnimal.vue')
}
```

However when the code inside the `GetAnimal.vue` gets executed I get this in console:

[image]

And I get directed to `http://localhost:8080/`.

I also tried

```js
...
this.$router.push({
    name: "viewanimal",
});
...
```

but it doesn't work either.

**EDIT**:

I've tried:
**router.js**:

```
  {
            path: "/viewanimal",
            name: "viewanimal",
            component: () => import('./views/DisplayAnimal.vue')
        },
        {
            path: "/getanimal",
            name: "getanimal",
            component: () => import('./views/GetAnimal.vue')
        }
```

**GetAnimal.vue**:

```
 console.log("this.animal: " + JSON.stringify(this.animal));  //displays good JSON

                this.$router.push({
                     name: "viewanimal",
                    params: this.animal
                 });
```

**DisplayAnimal.vue**:

```
created() {
            console.log("animal param: " +
                JSON.stringify(this.$route.params.animal)); //prints undefined
          }
```

---The animal parameter doesn't seem to have been passed. I'm not sure if it's the problem with the router's path/name thing or something else---.

**UPDATE**:

Managed to make it work. This should be in `GetAnimal.vue`:

```
    this.$router.push({
                     name: "viewanimal",
                    params: {
                         animal: this.animal
                     }
                 });
```

Comment: Is the given answer worked?

Comment: It should be `this.$router.push({ path: '/viewanimal' })` or `this.$router.path('/viewanimal')`.

Comment: @tony19 No. This: stackoverflow.com/a/50082888/4759176 says that if I want to pass parameters path won't work and I must use name instead.

Comment: @parsecer That intention was not apparent in your original question, which had no parameters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to define the routes as named route in the router.js file. Your routes missing the `name` attribute. For named routes, the name attribute is must. It should be like the given example,

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
        path: "/viewanimal",
        name: "animal",
        component: () => import('./views/DisplayAnimal.vue')
    },
    {
        path: "/getanimal",
        name: "animal.get",
        component: () => import('./views/GetAnimal.vue')
    }
  ]
})
```

Focus on the `name` attribute, this is the route name you can use in template as given,

```html
<router-link :to="{ name: 'animal'}">Animals</router-link>
```

Alternatively, here is the code to push new route,

```js
router.push({ name: 'animal'})
```

If you don't want to go through naming all of the routes you can push the route path as `router.push({ path: '/viewanimal' })`, but the named routes are more clean approach.

Comment: This: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50082888/4759176 says that if I want to pass parameters `path` won't work and I **must** use `name` instead. I tried replacing `path` with `name`: `name: "/viewanimal"` and my parameter data didn't seem to have been passed

Comment: Please see the edit on my question - I tried to adapt your code, but it doesn't seem to be working with parameters

Comment: Either you use named route or path, passing parameter works both ways. Well, your code is now working and that's an important thing:)