# Using VueX to add an element to an array and remove an element from the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuex

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-script-setup-with-vuex-gfjaff?file=src/components/UserProfile.vue

I'm trying to be able to enter a name into the dispatch function and add it to an array. (Eventually I'd like to add a text input field, and enter it from there. Baby steps)

Then I'd like to be able to click a delete button near those names to delete it. I'm having a problem trying to implement "event.target.value". I think that's the problem anyways.

What am I doing wrong in this code? What part am I getting wrong?

**store.js**

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  state: () => ({
    list: ['bob', 'joe', 'harry'],
  }),
  getters: {
    listStatus: (state) => state.list,
  },
  actions: {
    addName({ commit }, { name }) {
      commit('ADD_NAME', name)
    },
    removeName({commit}, {name}) {
      commit('REMOVE-NAME', name)
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_NAME(state, name) {
      state.list.push(name)
    },
    REMOVE_NAME(state, event_target_name){
      state.list.filter(element=>element !== event_target_name)
    }
  },
})
```

**userList.vue**

```
<template>
  <div v-for="name in listStatus">
    <li>{{ name }}</li>
    <button @click="removeName(event.target.value)">Remove</button>
  </div>
  <button @click="addName">ADD NAME</button>
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

const store = useStore()
const listStatus = computed(() => store.getters.listStatus)
// const addName = (input_name) => store.dispatch('addName', { name: input_name }) --------- DOESN'T WORK
const addName = () => store.dispatch('addName', { name: 'tommy' })
const removeName = (event) => store.dispatch('remove-name', { name: event.target.value })
</script>
```

Comment: filter creates a new array. it doesnt act on the array from which it is called. So in REMOVE_NAME, 1) you're creating a new array and assigning it to nothing. 2) your original array (state.list) remains the same.

Comment: And there's a couple of other things that are wrong as well. I forked your example and fixed the stuff that's wrong (left the wrong stuff commented out) https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-script-setup-with-vuex-fw5kds?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FUserProfile.vue,src%2Fstore.ts,src%2Fshims-vue.d.ts

Comment: [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-script-setup-with-vuex-5fuhjp?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FUserProfile.vue,src%2Fstore.ts). Tip: take it slowly and use `console.log` at every step.

Comment: And one more thing: swap `vuex` for [pinia](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-script-setup-with-vuex-jejjfr?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FUserProfile.vue). Much cleaner syntax. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71596533/1891677) for a longer list of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$event` to access the event in an inline handler.

```
<button @click="removeName($event.target.value)">
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#accessing-event-argument-in-inline-handlers)-

> A method handler automatically receives the native DOM Event object
> that triggers it.

In your case, when the `remove` button triggers the `removeName` method, it will auto-receive the `event`, you don't need to pass it unless this is the only param you are passing.

Now, there are two problems in your code-

1. You are passing `event` but you should use `$event`, a special variable. If you want to pass `event`, then use arrow function syntax. [Read here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#calling-methods-in-inline-handlers).
2. Even if `removeName(event.target.value)` works, then it means you are already passing the target value, then inside the method, you should access it like `removeName(target_value)` not `removeName(event)`. By doing that, you are further trying to access value from the value itself.

So, do the following fixes in your code and it should work-

`In template-`

```
 <button @click="removeName">Remove</button>
```

`In JS (same as you are using)-`

```
const removeName = (event) => store.dispatch('remove-name', { name: event.target.value })
```